# How to access the current tab's LocalStorage and Cookies from the popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop an extension that clears the current tab(domaine)'s localStorage and cookies from the popup.
The Popup is a simple react application, that has a button, and an onClick handle that execute the following function:

```js
const removeLocalStorage = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
        chrome.storage.sync.clear()
    });
}
```

This does nothing.

Comment: Use chrome.browsingData.remove()

Comment: I need to delete only the cookies and localstorage for a certain website, not the whole data.

Comment: See the documentation and specify `origin`.